# AdventureWorks 2016 subquery not functional

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

From the AdventureWorks 2016 sample database, I need to list the vendors who have sold products in a qty of greater than 15 per sale.

I wrote the below SQL statements, however I don't think it is right as I only get 6 results but I am sure there are more. I was not able to find a 2 tables that had a matching key so I thought I had to use 3 which made it harder for me. Anyways does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Or is there a simpler way to write this that I don't know about? My instructor is not very helpful

```
SELECT Name
FROM Purchasing.Vendor AS PV
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT BusinessEntityID
              FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor AS PPV
              WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ProductID
                            FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SSOD
                            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT OrderQty
                                          FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SSOD
                                          WHERE OrderQty > 15
                                            AND SSOD.ProductID = PPV.ProductID)
                              AND PPV.BusinessEntityID = PV.BusinessEntityID))
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Why are you not able to use JOINs or UNIONs?

Comment: Marc raised an interesting point in his answer. Do you have the correct tables? Sales are different than Purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - it returns 58 rows for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Purchasing.Vendor AS PV
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader POH ON POH.VendorID = PV.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod ON pod.PurchaseOrderID = POH.PurchaseOrderID
WHERE pod.OrderQty > 15
ORDER BY Name
```

You need to join the `Purchasing.Vendor` table with the `PurchaseOrderHeader` and `PurchaseOrderDetail` tables to get the information about the purchases made by Adventure Works that you're looking for

Comment: @Gina: ***WHY NOT???*** That is the **preferred** way of doing things - these "cascades" of `EXISTS()` are just a hack and not the way to go.....

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can do a better job than the instructor.

`EXISTS()` is a function that will return a boolean value (true or false) determining if there are rows in the query contained in it. When used in a `WHERE` clause, it's usually containing a correlated sub-query, which means that the query within the `EXISTS()` references at least one column from the outer query. That said, let's go step by step.

First we need to find the Vendors with Purchase Orders.

```
SELECT *
FROM Purchasing.Vendor v
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT *
                FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader poh 
                WHERE poh.VendorID = v.BusinessEntityID);
```

You can see that I'm using a * instead of a column or column list. This is because the columns are not used by the `EXISTS()` function, only rows. I'm also correlating the inner query using a WHERE clause that references a column from the outside query.

Once we have the orders, we need to go to the detail to see which of them have products with a quantity over 15.

```
SELECT *
FROM Purchasing.Vendor v
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT *
                FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader poh 
                WHERE poh.VendorID = v.BusinessEntityID -- we keep the relation
                AND EXISTS( SELECT *                    -- and add another condition
                            FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod
                            WHERE pod.PurchaseOrderID = poh.PurchaseOrderID -- once again we create a relation
                            AND pod.OrderQty > 15)                          -- and add another condition
             );
```

Hopefully, this can clear out how to use `EXISTS()` and how to cascade them. These can be more efficient than JOINs because they don't take into account columns and can short-circuit on the first row found. This is internally called as a semi-join.

Comment: That's just because you mentioned that your results were incorrect. If you follow the same process of thought using sales table, you arrive to 6 vendors. Your code didn't return an incorrect result, it just had some indications of lack of understanding on how EXISTS work. That's why I took the time to go step by step.